# Creating Microsoft account, stuck at solving puzzle

Tags: outlook.com, account-management, microsoft

I'm creating a new account for my wife, and I'm stuck at this robot puzzle. Each time I solve it it just sends me back to solving it again. I tried different browsers, different emails, different sites (Outlook and Hotmail), different computers, tried cleaning cache, doing it from incognito mode etc.
When searching the only hits are on Microsoft Answers, which are not helpful as usual. But seems like the bug is around since end of 2021. Does anyone have any solution to this?

[image: "Create account: Pick the image of 2 checkered shapes" with 6 images]

Comment: I wish I could post the answer but not enough reputation. So here it is: A post about it working on iPhone, gave me a clue, so I tried a private window on Firefox on my Android phone, and it finally worked. This is after getting the endless loop on Firefox, Chrome and Edge on Windows 10. Apparently it is using the mobile site, not the desktop site, that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different browsers?  It eventually worked for me in a private window on Firefox.  Nothing else had worked before that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several browsers in the normal window as well as the incognito/private windows which in the last worked for me on the **private window of Firefox**.